# Random bit double questions

Tags: casting, double, endianness, nstimeinterval

I saw the following line in [GTMHTTPFetcher.m](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/source/browse/trunk/Source/GTMHTTPFetcher.m#1259) of [gtm-http-request](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/):

```
// set min interval to a random value between 1.0 and 2.0 seconds
minRetryInterval_ = 1.0 + ((double)(arc4random() & 0x0FFFF) / (double) 0x0FFFF);
```

1. Why are both operands of the division operator being cast to `double`s?
2. What does the `& 0x0FFFF` do?
3. Does this work independent of the system's [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?
4. How can we be sure that `0x0FFFF` is always larger than `arc4random() & 0x0FFFF`? What if the system uses two's compliment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Both operands of the division operator are being cast to `double`s because `minRetryInterval_` is an `NSTimeInterval`, which is of `typedef double`. Perhaps, it might make more sense to cast them both to `NSTimeInterval`s instead.
2. The `& 0x0FFFF` zeros out all but the right-most 16 bits of the random `u_int32_t`, i.e., `unsigned int`, generated by `arc4random()`.
3. Yes, this should work independent of the system's endianness because the denominator, `0x0FFFF`, is the largest possible 16 bit `double`, and so, the quotient will always be less than or equal to 1.
4. The most significant bit of a [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) is a [sign bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit). In this case, both sign bits are 0, so we can be sure the quotient will be positive. Also, according to the specification for `double`, `0x0FFFF` is greater in magnitude than `0x0FFFE`, for example.